# Finding if the branch is at the head in git

Tags: git

If I have a branch setup and I have pushed it remotely for other to share and work on. Is there a command in git to check if my branch is at the HEAD? I assume if someone has committed and pushed changes form their machine to remote which I have not pulled down yet, that means my local branch is not at the HEAD.

I see, I can do

```
git diff testbr origin/testbr
```

If this returns something, it means local testbr is not at the HEAD.
or I can also do if

```
git fetch returns empty update
```

or

```
git log HEAD..<remoteBr> --oneline
```

Is there a simple true or false answer instead of me parsing the output of these commands.

Comment: Side note: usual git workflows suppose that everyone just do pull as early as common sense tells - before every local change, before pushing. This way local active branch is always up to date.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. But I am doing this from some automation code.

Comment: Can't you pull automatically?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to fetch, you have to parse the commit ID from [`git ls-remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote.html).  For example, if you do

```
git ls-remote origin testbr
```

you might see

```
728f270f6850706a3ac1990da4c44589eb6d38f7        refs/heads/testbr
```

And you can use [`cut`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cut-invocation.html) in the shell to get the first field.

To get the commit ID of the local branch you can use [`git rev-parse`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse) like

```
git rev-parse testbr
```

So in a shell script you just compare the commit IDs:

```
[ `git ls-remote origin testbr | cut -f1` == `git rev-parse testbr` ]
```

If you are willing to fetch first, then you can just do

```
[ `git rev-parse testbr` == `git rev-parse origin/testbr` ]
```

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for more of true/false answer. But looks like it doesn't exist. So I will use git log HEAD along with git fetch.